# How can I divide a set of strings into their constituent characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

What is the best way to separate the individual characters in an array of strings `strArr` into an array of those characters `charArr`, as depicted below?

```
string[] strArr = { "123", "456", "789" };
char[] chrArr = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
```

This is what I am currently doing, but I do not think that it is very elegant:

```
int characterCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
{
    characterCount += strArr[i].Length;
}

int indexCount = 0;
char[] chrArr = new char[characterCount];

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < strArr[i].Length; j++)
    {
        chrArr[indexCount] = strArr[i][j];
        indexCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, *easiest* way would be this:

```
char[] chrArr = string.Join(string.Empty, strArr).ToCharArray();
```

To make sure there is no confusion over performance characteristics here, here is a short program to test in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) (don't forget to turn on optimizations  in the lower right corner):

```
static string[] strArr = { "123", "456", "789" };

void Main()
{
    const int iterations = 10000000; // 10 million

    // Warm up JITter
    StringJoin();
    LINQSelectMany();
    LINQ();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
        StringJoin();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("String.Join");

    sw.Restart();
    for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
        LINQSelectMany();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("LINQ SelectMany");

    sw.Restart();
    for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
        LINQ();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("LINQ");
}

public static void StringJoin()
{
    char[] c = string.Join(string.Empty, strArr).ToCharArray();
}

public static void LINQSelectMany()
{
    char[] c = strArr.SelectMany(s => s).ToArray();
}

public static void LINQ()
{
    var characters = (from s in strArr
                      from c in s
                      select c).ToArray();

}
```

You can download this LINQPad script [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/26kn5uoeco3oyj8/SO16844986.linq?v=1mci) if you want to play with it.

Output (in milliseconds):

```
String.Join 
765 

LINQ SelectMany 
5098 

LINQ 
5465
```

*(the usual caveat about performance measuring code applies here, point out any mistakes I made)*

Comment: Please define "appropriate". A simple performance test shows that my line outranks the SelectMany line by a factor of 8. Since neither seems to offer any specific benefits over the other (like handling edgecases or whatnot better), I'd take the faster one if I can. Personally I don't feel like they are that much different in terms of readability either.

Comment: *appropriate* (adj.): Suitable or proper in the circumstances. :) - I wasn't saying you were wrong, I was simply saying it "seemed" more intuitive (or C# idiomatic) to use LINQ. Feel free to disagree though.

Comment: Yeah, strings and their string methods are very highly optimised indeed!

Comment: +1 for performance measurements and reasonable comments in discussion section

Comment: @TimothyShields "intuitive" and "appropriate" are subjective. LINQSelectMany made me look into documentation in order to understand it and LINQ made me reread it couple of times because of non descriptive variable names and because multiple `from` statements are a little foreign for me. On the other hand I understood StringJoin immediately. Linq would be more intuitive from my perspective if `SelectMany` was named "Concat" (exists but...) or "Flatten".

Answer (score 19):

I would do:

```
char[] chrArr = strArr.SelectMany(s => s).ToArray();
```

Comment: I can't belive this answer gets 2 upvotes and the silly one 14.

Comment: @I4V What? What do you mean?

Comment: Shorter does not mean better, and in terms of minimising time, I think you should actually do some performance measurements to make sure that statement is true :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hah yes, you're not wrong about making measurements. :) On reflection, I expect string Join() is faster, but takes more memory.

Comment: I doubt it will use more memory. Yes, it'll build up a single string from string.Join before converting to a char array, while `ToArray` will build up a list before returning a new array. Since a list usually ends up with more capacity than actually needed, I naively think the string.Join method will outrank here too, but I don't have a solid way of measuring this so I'll keep this thought to myself :)

Comment: There's not much point in being "right" here, since the example code in the question is contrived for this particular question, the LINQ way certainly has merit, and while *I* would use the `string.Join` method if I can, this code might not even be a bottleneck so if the LINQ way is more readable to other developers, to each their own. I would not go so far as to say the LINQ method is wrong, but it does pay to know a lot of the non-LINQy framework code, just because LINQ is the "new wave" does not mean all the old code is bad, slow or wrong. I liked the LINQ examples though :)

Comment: I must admit, *"the silly one"* suprised me with the test results (I did my own tests also).

Answer (score 7):

```
var res = strArr.SelectMany(c => c.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can I ask why while `ToCharArray` is unnecessary?

Comment: @I4V Good point. You're right, and I missed that. I liked it because of SelectMany(), and preferred it to the other SelectMany() because of "var" instead of char[].

Answer (score 3):

LINQ based version would be:

```
var input = new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var characters = (from s in input
                  from c in s
                  select c).ToArray();

foreach (var c in characters) Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an extension of Jesse Slicer's answer.

Simply cleaning up your code with ReSharper (if you don't have this or something like it, go get it now) yields this:

```
var characterCount = strArr.Sum(t => t.Length);

var indexCount = 0;
var chrArr = new char[characterCount];

foreach (var t1 in strArr.SelectMany(t => t))
{
    chrArr[indexCount] = t1;
    indexCount++;
}
```

The `foreach` is just filling an array and there's already a LINQ method `ToArray` for that.  Then `characterCount` and `indexCount` are completely unnecessary.

```
var chrArr = strArr.SelectMany(t => t).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 string value="";
 string[] strArr = { "123", "456", "789" }; //Your string array.

 for(int i=0;i<strArr.Length;i++)
 {
     value+=strArr[i];
 }
  char [] array=value.ToCharArray();
```